# Error when starting ArcGIS Server Object Manager (v10)

Tags: arcgis-server

I just finished installing ArcGIS Server 10 and completed the post-installation. The ArcGIS Server Object Manager service is installed, but when I try to start it, I get the following error:

"Windows could not start the ArcGIS Server Object Manager service on the Local Computer.

Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."

The agsadmin and agsusers groups exist, and my local account is a member of the agsadmin group.

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thanks,

Jon.

Answer (score 1):

You may use gis.stackexchange.com for this question

10 SP3 upgrade is available: 
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1808

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/10168-Error-when-starting-ArcGIS-Server-Object-Manager-%28v10%29

Answer (score 0):

You also should look in the Application and System logs (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer) for clues as to why the service failed to start.  Does it have some kind of dependency that is not being met?

Also, services often fail to start because they do not have valid credentials:

1. Start -> Run -> services.msc
2. Right-click on the "ArcGIS Server Object Manager" service and choose Properties
3. Select the "Log On" tab
4. Enter a valid username/password (if you are not sure whether the service account you are currently using has sufficient permissions, you can use a local admin account temporarily for testing purposes)

Comment: Dependencies are all running. Event logs are showing generic error codes & messages. The service is using valid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting passwords for  SOM, SOC and ArcGISWebServices accounts